Information on sample pooling strategies
I am looking for information about a specific sort of problem: There is a set of samples, and some subset of them are positive.  It is possible to combine samples and test if the combination contains any positive samples.  Given the cost of a test and some prior probabilities, how do you optimally choose test batches to find the positive samples?
This seems like a situation that has been thoroughly studied, but I haven't found much on google.
It is possible to model and track every 2^n possible situations, and then choose the most informative batches.  But this is intractable for a large number of samples.
I am interested in optimal and heuristic solutions.  Also variations where tests can be run in parallel, if there are other constraints like worst case time.
Something like this may have happened during covid under the name “sample pooling”.  But I haven’t seen anything that approaches the problem from an algorithmic perspective.

This kind of batching idea has been studied for Covid tests, and I believe there were some research results on using error-correcting codes to construct the batches (maybe from researchers/academics in Israel?).

This is group testing problem.
